# supporting paging as user scrolls through WPF datagrid bound to a dataview

Tags: wpf, datagrid, paging, dataview

How do I support paging on the WPF datagrid that is bound to a dataview ? Paging should happen
as user scrolls through the datagrid. I retrieve 100 rows per page from the DB and load them up in
dataview which is bound to a grid. I need a way to detect if user has scrolled to the end of the page and get dataview to retrieve the next 100 rows from the DB. I am not sure if this is possible.
If possible, whats involved in getting this done. I am using MVVM pattern. Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks
Ramakrishna